# Java Callable async without executor

Tags: java, asynchronous, executorservice, callable, executor

I looked around there are many examples but could not find a direct answers. Please see the code below. I dont want to submit my callable tasks to an executor to get a future. I just want to call it as raw. So I call the .call() directly is this going to block the current thread? I mean is it going to be blocking call? Thanks

```
public class CustomCallable implements Callable<Long> {
private long number;

public CustomCallable(final long number) {
    this.number = number;
}

@Override
public Long call() throws Exception {
     //do something    
    return number;
  }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Callable<Long> cCallable = new CustomCallable(i);
            cCallable.call();//The question is: is this going to block until it finishes the current call, or continue spinning others. Is the loop going to continue without waiting the previous call? or just continue until it reaches <10? 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Calling `.call()` is just a regular method call. Since the method returns a value, you cannot really convert it to a `Runnable`, otherwise you could use [`Executor.execute(Runnable command)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute-java.lang.Runnable-)

Comment: @Turing85 Yes, however you **can** wrap a `Callable<T>` in a `FutureTask<V>` then call an `Executor`'s `.execute` on that.

Comment: first of all call method in callable is is just like a method in any class.. by invoking call, it will execute synchronously. 
to make it asynchronous you either create a Thread, or executor service, etc..
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/callable-future-java/